# Normalization for MLPregressor

Tags: python, scikit-learn, normalization, activation-function

I'm using scikit-learn, and trying to understand how normalize my input variables, for different activation functions using MLPregressor:

- Relu
- Tanh
- Logistic

How can i properly normalize the data for this activation functions?

Comment: Look into [SKLearn's preprocessing](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.preprocessing) tools. You might transform your data before passing to MLPRegressor using StandardScaler.

Comment: I'm going to study about it, thank you Jarad!